# Check if email is taken and code is correct in signup

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Trying to check if either email is taken, code is wrong, or both are wrong in node. this is my code thus far:

```
app.post('/auth/signup', function (req, res) {
var code = Access.findOne({ accesscode: 'secretpassword' }, { _id: 0, accesscode: 1 }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, existingUser) {
  if (existingUser) {
     return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Email is already taken' });
  }
  else if (code != req.body.access) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Access code is wrong' });
  }else {
    var user = new User({
        displayName: req.body.displayName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        isAdmin: false,
    });
  }
  user.save(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    }
    res.send({ token: createJWT(result) });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to check if req.body.access from the signup form is equal to the accesscode field in the Access mongoose schema.

How do I only get the 'secretpassword' when querying with mongoose? Currently I get { accesscode: 'secretpassword'};

And are the if/else-if's correct?

EDIT:

I managed to fix it.

instead of setting it to var code = Access.findOne I did it like this:

```
var code;
Access.findOne({ accesscode: 'secretpassword' }, { _id: 0, accesscode: 1 }, function (err, data) {
    code = data.accesscode;
});
```

This way it stores the accesscode value into code and we can continue using it in the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the 'jsonwebtoken' module to do the code part. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-web-token

So for generation/verification of code (token) it should look like:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

// Generate code
jwt.sign({sub:email,purpose:"signup"},signkey,{algorithm:"HS256"});

// Verify the code
var decoded = jwt.verify(code,signkey,{algorithms:"HS256"});
if (decoded.purpose !== "signup") {
        throw new Error("invalid purpose");
}
if (decoded.sub !== getObjectProperty(res, emailProperty)) {
        throw new Error("invalidactivationcode");
}
```

As for user email checking there are plenty of example out there in the net using mongodb.

Comment: the code in question is not the token, but the 'accesscode' in the Access Schema.
I want to check if the content of 'accesscode' is equal to req.body.access that comes from the signup form, but I don't seem to get that part working, hence the initial question.